# Display the value of time from php url

Tags: php, datetime

How would I display the value of time with the following URL?

```
August.php?view=display&time=2016-08-30
```

If I am understanding correctly, August.php is my page, display$time is my variable. I haven't been able to find anything on what a view is in PHP.

I've tried the following code:

```
$time = $_GET[‘display&time’];
echo time(“H:i:s”, $time);
```

I'm new to PHP and still learning the syntax. Thanks!

Comment: you should get like this $time = $_GET['time'];  echo $time;

Comment: Understanding url parameters is important, and not specific to PHP.... `print.php?view=display&time=2013-01-04` has 2 arguments, one called `view` with a value of `display`, the second called `time` with a value of `2013-01-04`

Comment: Thank you for clearing that up Mark! That makes more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be :

```
$time = $_GET['time'];
echo time("H:i:s", $time);
```

After ? there is a list of key=value parameters separated by &

Comment: Thank you vincenth! "key=value parameters" was the part of my understanding I was missing

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$time = $_GET['time'];
echo time("H:i:s", $time);
```

as the holder for time in URL is time not display&time